# The percentage of utilization for the single level mux implementation

Tags: multiplexer

Is the percentage of utilization equal to 100% here? If so, can I calculate the utilization like this?

$$\frac 4 4 \cdot 100 = 100%$$

[image]

Also, I have to sketch a 2-level MUX implementation based on 2-1 multiplexers (74157 devices). Is my sketch right?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. How about posting what you've tried so far?

Comment: the homework asked me to calculate the percentage and i did then i get 100% but i am not sure and i am asking if my answer which is 100% is right or wrong

Comment: Utilization of what? space on a sheet of paper? electricity?

Comment: the Q was like this:- the percentage of utilization for the single level MUX implementation

Comment: is this implemented in an FPGA or a CPLD? Those have a fixed amount of resources on-chip, so percent utilization would make sense in that context. Comparing how many logic elements does your FPGA chip have, and how many of those available elements this design requires. Depends on the FPGA (see datasheet) and the design.

Comment: we are not given any information about how is this implemented

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is implemented using 2 [74153](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74153) parts, which are dual 4-to-1 muxes. As we can see both muxes in both ICs are utilized, so the utilization of these ICs is indeed 100%. Unless the "utilization" is referring to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2-input mux circuit will work, but it's not what they're looking for. Try making a 4-input mux using 2 2-input muxes which feed a third 2-input mux.